# JBPM console: How to get list of users in group

Tags: jbpm

I am creating a process that will have user tasks that are assigned by groups. There is a weird business rule that there is no guarantee that someone will be assigned to a given group. I need the process to go into an alternate flow if there is no one assigned to a given role.

My initial plan was to somehow get a list of users in the specified group and use the isEmpty method in the connection expressions. Is this possible? Is it possible to simply skip a user task if no one is assigned to the group? If so, would I need to lookup the process history through an Audit service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently get information about users and groups by delegating (by default) to JAAS.  This however does not allow us to query which users are part of which group.  So the only option do this currently would be do implement this yourself.  For example, your security domain might be configured to use a database for user/group mgmt, or LDAP.  In that case, your rule might try to query that information from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kris Verlaenen.  I was hoping to avoid custom code, but your explanation makes it clear why I must.